# Setting the value from an outer class to the value retrieved in the inner class

Tags: java, android, global-variables, retrofit2, inner-classes

I have a fragment in my android app, the idea is to pull info from a json file (github) and parse that for titles, which is then updated into my recyclerview. I can pull the data just fine, got it in a List, which is my schema.

Now this data is in the "onResponse" inner class, that is also in the "onCreateView" innerclass.

The code to update my recyclerview is in the onCreateView innerclass. How do I pass the list from the onResponse, to onCreate, or even to the globallevel?

In that class, i've 2 global variables:

```
static List<GithubRepo> list  = new ArrayList<>();
static List<String> List_body = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, in the inner class "Create" method that creates my view, I'm using retrofit to parse the json of github to get some repository names.

I can get them just fine, but when I get the list from "response.body" then parse it properly into string getting only the titles using:

```
private void setList(List<GithubRepo> repo){
    if (repo != null) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (GithubRepo r : repo) {
            String name = r.getName().toString();
            List_body.add(name);
            counter++;
        }


    }
    else{
        Log.d("test:empty", "empty");
    }
}
```

GithubRepo above is merely the object structure for the json, i get the names in the inner class, set them, but they remain null when i try to apply the new list to my views. How do I set the values of a global/static variable from the variable in my inner class?

Here's the whole thing:

```
public class primary_fragment extends Fragment implements Agg_Adapter.ItemClickListener {

static List<GithubRepo> list  = new ArrayList<>();   <--------HOLDS value of schema object temporarily
static List<String> List_body = new ArrayList<>();   <--------UPDATES the recyclerview, currently empty
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


.... Some code

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
        @Override    <------------------------- From here is the inner class
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
            // 1. start
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {

                    list.addAll(response.body());
                    setList(list);
   });

  Log.d("testedB2!:", (List_body.toString()));  <------Should have the values set but it is null
```

It's probably something really simple but i've forgotten it! Let me know if i need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using Retrofit makes the call asynchronous. There's nothing wrong with that, in fact it's how it should be. However, the assumption that `List_body` should be filled in the line you print it to the log, is not correct. Simply put, before your network call finishes, the `Log.d` will run and print nothing.

There's different ways you can fix this. The simplest is to call a method from within `onResponse` that let's the fragment know the list is ready. For example:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
    @Override    
    public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                list.addAll(response.body());
                setList(list);
                onListReady();
     });
```

And once the method `onListReady()` gets called you can print the log statement if you want:

```
private void onListReady () {
     Log.d("testedB2!:", (List_body.toString()));
}
```

This you can implement in the fragment.

Like I said, there's different ways to do this. I'm just trying to show you that the call actually runs asynchronously.